# CAN CSMA-CD and Arbitration

Tags: can-bus

I have a doubt. I am working on CAN protocol which uses CSMA-CD and Arbitration mechanism to transfer message. I am planning to implement single Server Node and Multiple Client Nodes.

- Server is given `ID of 0 (11-bit Identifier)`.
- When node is powered on it should get a ID to communicate in the network so it requests one from Server. Node uses `Remote Frame` to request ID from server which involves `ID = 0 (Server ID), DLC = 2`

My doubt is, there are multiple nodes on the CAN Bus so each node requests an ID from Server. And all the nodes use `ID = 0 (Server ID), DLC = 2 as Remote Frame`. Now suppose 2 or more nodes at the same time sends message to server arbitration mechanism is not going to work because both the nodes get control over the CAN BUS. So did CSMA-CD will prevent this and allows only a single node to communicate at a given time?

Comment: What do you mean " CAN protocol which uses CSMA-CD"? CAN is using CSMA-CA or it isn't CAN, but some custom hogwash.

Comment: Overall, you misunderstand how CAN works on the fundamental level. It isn't node-driven, but message driven. CAN bus higher-tier protocols such as CANopen that use node id, use those as an offset to message identifiers. So if a certain type of message is sent with id 0x100, then the node with id 1 will send 0x101. Don't worry about node id until you have studied the basics of CAN itself though.

Answer (score 0):

If a device does not have an `ID`, `CSMA-CD` will not help because every node needs an `ID` in order to participate in the `CSMA-CD` flavor of the [CAN bus protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus#Data_transmission). Then, if it cannot access the bus, it cannot request an `ID`. As you see it is a chicken-egg kind of problem.

You could assign an unique `ID` to every node on the bus, then every node could request a new `ID`, but I guess that is like double-work...

Maybe it will be useful to learn about the [arbitration mechanism in CAN protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus#Data_transmission). In short: lower `ID` implies higher priority.